# Returning value outside of a stepper method (objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello I am new to iPhone and am working on creating my first application, my question:

I have 2 steppers being used and I want return the value of each stepper out of their respective method to be used in a separate method but the stepper method does not return a value. This is my current code, what do I need to add here (or add elsewhere in the program) to make this a possibility? Thank you

```
-(IBAction)numberOfPlayersStepper:(UIStepper *)numberOfPlayers{

numberOfPlayersLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",numberOfPlayers.value];

//how to return the numberOfPlayers.value to be used outside of this method?

}
```

Comment: Assign `numberOfPlayers.value` to a variable within your controller.

Comment: are you looking for something like UIControlEventValueChanged

Comment: As Conner wrote, declare an instance variable in your class. Store numberOfPlayers.value into it. voila.